# android - Can I Add ExpandableList in Dialog?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to show an ExpandableList in a Dialog. Is it possible to do so ? If yes then how ? Please help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this. One easiest way that I always prefer for customized dialogs is,

Build up your UI and corresponding java coding as a usual Activity. Then in manifest, specify its theme as a dialog.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
android:name="ClassName"></activity>
```

Comment: Thanks Nizam, i will follow this procedure itself.

Answer (score 3):

yes this is possible Create custom dialog and add expandable list in it's layout

and good tutorial for custom dialog is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Should work try this:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
TextView test = new TextView(this);
test.setText("test");
d.setContentView(test);
d.show();
```

Should work with more complex views defined by you:

```
LayoutInflater l = this.getLayoutInflater();
View v = l.inflate(R.id.yourView, false);
d.setContentView(v);
d.show();
```

Comment: thanks john, but i tried something similar. Unfortunately, the list items didn't populate. Hence, i asked the question here.

Comment: showing the activity as dialog would be a simpler and effective solution here.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to create an expandable list AlertDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643625/is-it-possible-to-create-an-expandable-list-alertdialog)

this link is also helpful for your problem it displays expendable list view in the dialog but 
to reduce the complexity you can create a activity with the expendable list view and show that activity as the dialog it would make it much more simpler

[Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

this is helpful in displating your activity as dialog.

Comment: Hi, I had seen the link which you've referred. But i guess, showing the activity as dialog would be a simpler option. Also, I am moving to other activity when an item is clicked. Thanks a lot for your help.